# Unique Alpha-Numeric code generation

Tags: c#-4.0, unique-key

I found this function on internet. this code is supposing generating a giving X lenght of unique string.I want to know if this function can truly generate a unique code without duplication. I want a  **unique code of 8 length**  for transaction purpose; Transaction like sending parcel details with a unique 8 length alpha-numeric key as identifier that need to be saved in the database.

```
public static string GetUniqueKey(int maxSize)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[62];
            chars =
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".ToCharArray();
            byte[] data = new byte[1];
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
            data = new byte[maxSize];
            crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
            foreach (byte b in data)
            {
                result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
```

NB: I dont want to check each time if the code exists before saving it, this is the reason why i am looking for a code that can return truly a unique key.

Comment: 8 length does not give you a lot to go with. I would use Guid and then retrieve the last 8 chars from that

Comment: Why don't you use an identity column which should be unique. Can't you use consecutive numbers? You could also derive the code from the PK-value like `RMA00000123`.

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig , does GUID guarantee the uniqueness and security of the key?

Comment: "Assuming uniform probability for simplicity, the probability of *one* duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth as of 2014 owned 600 million GUIDs." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: @TimSchmelter not a good idea because of the security of the key.

Comment: My weird answer is that - GUID does not theoretically guarantee uniqueness, but it does in practice.

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig the problem is that is the full length of the GUID that guarantee the unique key  such as {21EC2020-3AEA-4069-A2DD-08002B30309D}, but if i remove only the last 8 chars that may increase the probability of duplication of the generated key.

Comment: @Jmocke: i don't know the purpose of this code but i'm suprised that you expect it to be part of the application security.

Comment: of course you will. 8 chars will never guarantee uniqueness unless you sequence, and then you get n^8 (where n is the number of valid chars in your setup) before rollover

Comment: @TimSchmelter your example you gave `RMA00000123` is predictable and i mentioned the purpose of the unique key in the post. i am looking for a random unique key to be more precise. now for the security i can encrypt the key and use it.

Comment: why do you need 8 length? Guids would be perfect for your requirement in every other aspect than it's length

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig 8 digits for end users purpose. like the one money gram or western union transfer code give.

Comment: @Jmocke: something unique can be predictable and something unpredictable can be repeating, but never mind.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i agree with you.

Comment: You're probably thinking you're getting little help, but what we're getting at is that your requirement is a known problem with a known answer. You cannot come up with anything that guarantee a unique string of 8 length without history check. It's just not doable. The code you've found is probably as close as you'll get.

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig so i have to do wit it and check if t does exist before ? performance issues related ? :) but i think i will do it with that .

Comment: The likelihood of hitting a duplicate with that algorithm is fairly low, assuming a perfect RNG its 1/36^8